# Qmake - how to configure include path order?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake, opensuse, clang++

I have Qt-Creator on OpenSUSE. In it a have a C++ project with compiler 'clang'. There I have this '.pro' configuration:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/include/c++/v1/"

LIBS += "-stdlib=libc++"

LIBS += "/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/lib/libc++abi.a"

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++

TARGET = testCpp

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

And when I compile I got this output:

```
clang++ -c -pipe -Qunused-arguments -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/unsupported/linux-clang -I../testCpp -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include -I/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/include/c++/v1 -I. -I../testCpp -I. -o main.o ../testCpp/main.cpp
```

I want it to be either:

```
clang++ -c -pipe -Qunused-arguments -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/include/c++/v1 -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/unsupported/linux-clang -I../testCpp -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include -I. -I../testCpp -I. -o main.o ../testCpp/main.cpp
```

Or:

```
clang++ -c -pipe -Qunused-arguments -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/include/c++/v1 -o main.o ../testCpp/main.cpp
```

In other words - I want to either include this path (

> -I/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/include/c++/v1

) before the system defined ones or to completely remove them and leave only it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into `qmake` source, for example `Win32MakefileGenerator::writeStandardParts()` or `UnixMakefileGenerator::writeMakeParts()` you will see that the flags are included in the following order:

1. `QMAKE_CC`
2. `QMAKE_CXX`
3. `QMAKE_CFLAGS`
4. `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`
5. `INCLUDEPATH`
6. ...

`INCLUDEPATH` always goes after the first four. You can use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` and add `-I` path there:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -I/✪Data_Disk⚜✼/Build/include/c++/v1
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks

Comment: @MickyDuncan I agree, that was too little for the answer.